# How to check k8s deploy history?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes

I tried `kubectl rollout history deployment/my-app`, it returns only `No rollout history found.`

I think there exists a method to get all the deploy histories. It will be very helpful.

Reference official document: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `--record` while creating the deployment so that it will start recroding the deployment into the ReplicaSet.

```
$ kubectl create -f deploy.yaml --record=true
```

Whenever you deploy new version of deployment, the replica set preserves the previous configuration of the deployment. Check the track of deployment and even we can use this for automation. This should be the default option in the kuberentes deployment, but, by default it's set to false.

Then check the status and history using the below commands,

```
$ kubectl rollout status deploy myapp-deployment
$ kubectl rollout history deploy myapp-deployment
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

its very often when "rollout history" shows nothing.
there is the way out - find all  replica set of the deployment
and check their "describe". so you can get all the history information
you need.

an example:

```
# kubectl get rs | grep -E "NAME|depl3"
NAME                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
depl3-599bb89957                    0         0         0       63m
depl3-9759cc7f6                     0         0         0       41h
depl3-fc57c9788                     2         2         2       41h



# kubectl describe rs  depl3-599bb89957  |  grep -E "revision:|Image"
                deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 3
    Image:        nginx:1.7.6



# kubectl describe rs  depl3-9759cc7f6      |  grep -E "revision:|Image"
                deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 4
    Image:        nginx:1.7.9


# kubectl describe rs    depl3-fc57c9788      |  grep -E "revision:|Image"
                deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 5
    Image:        nginx:1.7.9
```

"revision" shows  time sequence of replica sets.